# Setting Cookie in javascript and reading it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

So I have a cookie set through js when the user accepts a popup, it is set through the following function.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
setCookie("accepted_popup", 'accepted_value', 1);
```

When checking the Cookie in chrome dev tools it is set indeed.

```
Name           |Value          |Domain       |Path  |Expires                    |Size   |HttpOnly   |Secure |SameSite   |Priority
accepted_popup |accepted_value |example.com  |/     |2020-07-09T15:07:43.000Z   |11     |           |       |        |Medium
```

I realize that for the cookie to take effect on the server it would need a page load. So I don't want the popup to show next time the page loads, so I'm checking the Cookie on the server like this.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['accepted_popup'])){
        doSomething();    //not showing popup
    }else{
        showPopup();      //showing popup
    }
?>
```

What's new in this question that hasn't been asked before is that the above code was perfectly working on the old server, it stopped working when moving to AWS(if that might be a reason).
When I do `var_dump($_COOKIE);` on the server the cookie accepted_popup doesn't show in it.

Also I'm setting the cookie and retrieving it on the same domain(in production), say "example.com" no subdomain or www.

On my development site subdomain.example.com the above code is working fine, and behaving as expected.

Comment: Hi,  try set another cookie from PHP and then retrieve it, just to know it works

Comment: @RăducanuIonuţ I added `setcookie("TestingCookie", "Just a test", time()+86400);` and `setcookie("TestingCookie2", "Another test", time()+86400, "/", "example.com", 1);` from PHP, they didn't show on the next reload in the $_COOKIE variable

Comment: From php docs: If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE. If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return TRUE. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.

Can you check and see the return result?

Comment: If you get False, meaning that the cookie is not accepted I run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580256/cookies-not-set-using-php-setcookie-function.

The answer states that you should check $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] value.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turned out to be not in setting the cookie in PHP but in AWS CloudFront.
If anyone is facing the same problem and have AWS hosting, check

CloudFront Distributions -> Behaviors -> Default(*) either change the "Forward Cookies" option or set add the cookie names to the "Whitelist Cookies" as shown in the image.

[image: Aws set whitelisted cookies]